# View question while composing an answer

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

This may be a duplicate, but I did a thorough search and couldn't find it.

It would be useful to have the original question visible when composing an answer. I often want to reference the question to use the askers variable names, and check my wording.

Comment: The draft is saved, so you can cancel and then go back, but there's definitely room for improvement

Comment: I would like this for the android version too. Can i edit the tags?

Comment: Sure! By all means, be my guest.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232175/165952

Comment: @mhlester: But you have to confirm resuming from your draft, and don't get autosaved drafts when backing out of an edit (only from a new post). Not an optimal solution, especially since you can see both question and answer-in-progress on even the mobile website.

Comment: @rickster great point about the confirmation for drafts. I would love to see that made a lot more seamless, and have the app just assume I want to resume rather than need to ask me.