# View question while composing answer on Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Related: [View question while composing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232172/165952)

While writing answers, I feel it would be useful to see the question as well. It's great to make sure I can address all the concerns of a post.

I think it would also be great if it could be toggled on and off while composing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app has answer draft functionality built in. So, if you tap the <kbd><</kbd> button in the action bar when composing an answer you'll be able to interact with everything and resume your answer by tapping "Edit your answer draft"

Comment: Why status-completed?

Comment: @nicael I was attempting to close it as a duplicate of the feature request for the initial implementation of this but didn't find one, so I figured we'll use this as the canonical "how do I do this" question.